# Android HTTP Post request problem

Tags: android, http, post

I'm working on an issue which is:
+ I send a **HTTP POST** request to a server and get the response.
+ I use a ***DefaultHTTPClient*** instance to send the request. And I use ***BasicNameValuePair*** to add the params for the server to process.
There is a param which is a xml-based string. The problem is that, when I send an "empty" string like this: " ", the server response "*SUCCESSFUL*". But when I send another value which is much longer. The server response "*UNSUCCESSFUL*" due to this parameter.
Please tell me that whether Android has a max length limitation on BasicNameValue instance or not? And how can I fix this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have control over this web service? If so, check what's showing up server-side compared to what's being sent out Android-side. What is "much longer"? 10 bytes? 1000 bytes? One point twentyone jiggabytes?

Comment: I don't think there is length restriction. Have you tried sending short length three or four times to check connection properly..

Comment: A good way to debug your request is to hand build the call using a service call "hurl" - try this: http://hurl.it

Comment: @MarcB: I don't have control over this web service. It's done by another coder who offered me a simple HTML form to test the service. It works great on computer web browser.

Comment: @Stuti: I tried to send a smaller string. It works. And I tried to send another string (which is like this: "aaaaaaaaaa") with the same length with the wrong string, it also works.

Comment: @CaspNZ: the web services work great on computer browser.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the problem is with your web service, not with the `BasicNameValue` implementation on Android: you are probably just sending it a bad parameter. Do you get *SUCCESSFUL* when you send the exact same request parameters from another programming language?